# Flutter: how to globalize string return value from Telephony package?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, telephony

I want to make the string value global from its return value in `Telephony` package, like this:

```
void tel() {
    telephony.listenIncomingSms(
        onNewMessage: (SmsMessage message) {
          String adresse() {
            return message.address.toString();
          }
        }, //+977981******67, sender nubmer
        //1659690242000, timestamp

        onBackgroundMessage: backgrounMessageHandler,
        listenInBackground: true);
  }
```

I want the `adresse()` to be a global value with static access taken from the tel function.

Answer (score 0):

first, create a global String variable

```
String adress = "";
```

then in the `onNewMessage()` method:

```
adress = message.address.toString();
```

now you can use the `adress` variable with the value got from the `onNewMessage` globally

Comment: Thanks gwhyy, I will try that and respond to you. But does that make the global value of adress >message.address.toString(); does it not just make it equal to message.address.toString() ONLY inside the function?

Comment: no, the variable is global, then you canassign a value to it inside the function, then you can use it everywhere you want globally